# How does the bash for-loop know that a variable is a file

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have 3 files in current directory

```
t1
t2
t3
```

Command

```
for x in t* ; do echo $x ; done
```

returns

```
t1
t2
t3
```

How does for loop knows x is a file?

Comment: The for loop doesn't know or care about what x is.

Comment: right, its echo: echo t*

Comment: The answer is the same. The shell expands t* before calling echo. Can't you just read the manual? It's all written there.

Comment: where its explained in manual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to Bash's [Shell-Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), and more specifically [Filename-Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) and [Pattern-Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). You are using the `*` wildcard which matches "Matches any string, including the null string." So any files in the current directory that matching `t*` will be iterated over in the for loop. In this case it is just t1, t2, and t3.

That being said, Bash itself doesn't have the concept of "files" rather these are simple strings that point to a specific path on the file system, which can then be used with other commands. You can test if something is a file with the `-f` flag to the `test` command.

Comment: Note that `t*` expands into a list of matching filenames when the `for` loop is started. That is, `for x in t*` expands to the equivalent of `x in t1 t2 t3` before the loop is executed, so the loop runs three times with `x` set to "t1", then "t2", then "t3". But once the expansion has happened, the shell doesn't remember that those are filenames; after expansion, "t1", "t2", and "t2" are just strings as far as the shell is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

The `for-loop` does not know anything about files.  This is due to the [evaluation of the globs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).

Comment: "Evaluation of the Globs" sounds like it could be the title of a Starwars episode.   :+1:

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou It is actually a process of evaluation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy.

Comment: Personally, I'm looking forward to the sequel: Return of the Symbols!